# BotFramework-DirectLine JS - Initial Message Missing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a Bot I have built with MS BotFramework, hosted on Azure. The Bot is built to start the convo with a Welcome Message. When I test the bot through emulator, or on Azure test webchat, the bot will initiate the conversation as expected with the welcome message.

However, in my chat client using BotFramework-DirectLineJS, it isn't until I send a message that the bot will respond with the Welcome message (along with a response to the message the user just sent).

My expectation is that when I create a new instance of DirectLine and subscribe to its activities, this Welcome message would come through. However, that doesn't seem to be happening.

Am I missing something to get this functionality working?

Answer (score 0):

Given this is working for you on "Test in Webchat", I'm assuming your if condition isn't the issue, but check if it is `if (member.id === context.activity.recipient.id) {` (instead of `!==`). The default on the template is `!==` but that doesn't work for me outside of emulator. With `===` it works both in emulator and other deployed channels.

However, depending on your use cases you may want to have a completely different welcome message for Directline sessions. This is what I do. In my `onMembersAdded` handler I actually get channelId from the activity via `const { channelId, membersAdded } = context.activity;`. Then I check that `channelId != 'directline'` before proceeding.

Instead, I use the `onEvent` handler to look for and respond to the 'webchat/join' event from Directline. That leaves for no ambiguity in the welcome response. For a very simple example, it would look something like this:

```js
this.onEvent(async (context, next) => {
  if (context.activity.name && context.activity.name === 'webchat/join') {
    await context.sendActivity('Welcome to the Directline channel bot!');
  }

  await this.userState.saveChanges(context);
  await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);

})
```

You'll still want to have something in your `onMembersAdded` for non-directline channel welcome messages if you use this approach.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I will give that a look. I built my bot with BotFramework Composer, so I haven't really looked at the code of it - I assume your snippet is from the bot itself? I am more interested in the chat client and not as interested in the actual bot, but your suggestion makes sense so I will look there.

Comment: Yes, that is from my "main" bot file. You should be able to modify this in the bot code without breaking anything. This is what in most modern examples would be the root dialog. I am using the older setup where I have essentially an activity handler with no dialog of its own, but this should work in either case as it's just the welcome message. If you don't already have an `onEvent` handler, it should be wherever your existing `onMembersAdded` handler is. I'm not sure what you mean about the chat client vs. the bot, you are connecting to a bot using the chat client, no?